# How to only draw an objects shadow map in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Using three.js I have a scene with two objects. The first object is hovering over and casting a shadow onto the second object (a flat plane). Is there a way to only draw this shadow, but not the plane? The ultimate goal is to simulate casting a shadow onto the background HTML/CSS of the page.

Comment: Hmm, tricky. By definition the plane needs to have a material because the shadow is a function of the material surface and a light applied to it. Can you not simply use the plane as the background of the page?

Comment: There is a material specifically for this. See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/d8b24a1d2d4887a5db77d7112e5ba1539377c905/src/materials/ShadowMaterial.js it's now core and can be used like any other material.

Comment: The three.js object is just one of many elements on the page. The other elements are all CSS objects, so duplicating them in the canvas would be a lot more work.

Comment: The material solution, though not tested yet, seems to be ideal. Thanks! I will try this out on Monday and report back.

Comment: The ShadowMaterial solution worked perfectly. Thank you!